# "Your Android App Bundle has more than 1 certificate chain."

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

I built my app bundle using flutter and then signed it using the jarsigner as recommended.

`jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystore.jks -storepass *** -keypass *** signed.aab *keyalias*`

However, when I upload the app bundle to the google play store I get this error

> Your Android App Bundle has more than 1 certificate chain. Ensure your App Bundle has only 1 certificate chain and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have signing already configured by default in Flutter. If so, applying jarsigner again would sign it a second time.

If you want to sign using `jarsigner`, consider removing the [signing block](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle) from your Gradle config or manually deleting the `*.RSA`, `*.DSA` and `*.MF` files under the `META-INF` directory before running the `jarsigner` command.

Maybe better however would be to correctly set the signing configuration in the Gradle config directly so you don't have to run `jarsigner` at all.

Answer (score 1):

I signed my app using jarsigner with the wrong alias, then signed it with the correct alias causing this error. Rebuild your apk or aab then resign.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **`build.gradle.kts`** - there might be multiple `signingConfig` blocks or multiple places where the **signing configuration** is defined.

An example is this block of code which specifies a `signingConfigs{}` block but also initializes another **`debug`** signingConfig - see the commented line below on the **buildTypes** block.

```
//signing config block
signingConfigs {

       create("release") {

            .....

            storeFile = file("keystore/your_keystore.jks")
            storePassword = System.getenv("SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias = System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword = System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")


        }
    }
 
buildTypes {

        release {

            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            //signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")


        }

    }
```